# Why is sigprocmask called when calling the recv system call?

Tags: c++, linux

I've got some code that calls `recv()` periodically (with a `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag).  I'm curious because profiling my code in vtune, I see a `sigprocmask()` call associated with the `recv()`, and it's taking a large portion of the total time to execute.  I'm curious why `recv()` is calling `sigprocmask()`.

Comment: Can we see a relevant trace of the smallest possible code that reproduces this behavior?  Can we see that demo code, too?  It'd be illuminating to see precisely what is being done to the signal mask.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the context of those calls to `recv()`? What kind of socket are you using? Are you calling `recv()` directly?

Answer (score 1):

When working with TCP socket under linux, you'll receive SIGPIPE if the other side is closed unexpectedly.

Since you can mask this signal (most of the time, you'll handle the return value of 0 yourself, you don't care about this signal), I *guess* the system library checks for the signal state, and if masked, use a faster code path.

If not, it can't optimize.

BTW, you know about pselect() right ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably so recv can tell if relevant signals are generated that would otherwise not be seen if said signals were blocked.  EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK come to mind as values of errno that are sometimes generated using signals that could possibly be blocked.  Did you look at the [`sigprocmask` man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigprocmask.html)?

Comment: Brainfart, I meant errors.  Thanks.  The error is sometimes generated based on handled signals.